# assign decimal to a variable in solidity

Tags: solidity, error

I'm trying to calculate commission, but having a hard time doing a very easy math in Solidity.

Ex:

Commission = 5%

Sales = 100 ETH

100 x 5% (0.05) = 5 ETH

and in Solidity:

```
uint sales = 100;
uint afterCommission = sales * 0.05;
```

When I do this, I get

> > TypeError: Operator * not compatible with types uint256 and rational_const 1/2

Solidity can't assign a decimal points to a variable? How can I make this work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right, Solidity only supports integers. Try this instead:

```
uint sales = 100;
uint afterCommission = sales * 5 / 100; // 5%
```

If it's a variable amount but a whole number percent:

```
uint commissionPercentage = 7;
uint afterCommission = sales * commissionPercentage / 100; // 7%
```

If you need more decimal places:

```
uint commissionNumerator = 75;
uint commissionDenominator = 1000;
uint afterCommission = sales * commissionNumerator / commissionDenominator; // 7.5%
```

Comment: If you need to store percentage ownership, like one person had 79.5 % and the other person had 21.5%, would you store those percentages as two variables with the whole and the fraction?  Or would use use some math library and store 795 and 215?

Comment: This is not working for me pragma solidity >=0.6.12;